# Increasing kern.stackgap_random helps regarding security?

Tags: memory, stack

The default is:

```
kern.stackgap_random=262144
```

The system lets me modify it to max:

```
sysctl -w kern.stackgap_random=16777216
```

Will this increase security in an `OpenBSD 6.0` install?

This is the amount of stack randomization. It helps to prevent buffer overflows, but setting the value too big (`16777216?`) can cause more harm than help regarding security?

Also, don't know what are these values in, `262144 = 256 Mbyte`?